# XBMC crashing while playing SOME but NOT ALL videos

Tags: ubuntu, video, xbmc

I am using Frodo on Ubuntu 14.04.  XBMC is crashing when playing some but not all videos - most videos work.

My hardware specs (old computer)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
0b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
```

I am getting a segmentation fault error which isn't very helpful.  Is this a codec issue?  Any help fixing is greatly appreciated.  I haven't been able to find an answer on here or the Kodi forums regarding this issue.  Thanks!

My crash log:  http://pastebin.com/sCMNrz3J

Comment: Can you play the videos in another program? You may want to upgrade. Frodo is 2 releases old. Helix which is the first release of XBMC's new name KODI

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing from same problem when I ran my own addon kodi gave segmentation fault(core dumped) and stopped.

I totally removed kodi

> sudo apt-get autoremove kodi

The above command will remove kodi completely also.
Delete the ".kodi"(it's hidden so hit ctrl+h) directory in your home folder. After that do the following.

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get upgrade
>   sudo apt-get install kodi

Which installed the latest version of kodi with latest updates and the problem was solved